# Error on CORS express js with credentials true

Tags: express, next.js, cors

i am having problem with my cors, and i dont know why, i am using express on my backend,and there are three routes where i need to use credentials for the cookies, and now i am having problems when the api is deployed and my frontend too.

Here is my configuration of CORS in express:

```
    const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://sheol-shop.vercel.app/",
  credentials: true,
  methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH"],
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Content-Type",
    "Origin",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "Accept",
    "x-client-key",
    "x-client-token",
    "x-client-secret",
    "Authorization"
  ]
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

and this is my frontend client for the requests with axios

```
constructor(url: string = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api`) {
    this.client = axios.create({
      baseURL: url,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });

    this.client.interceptors.response.use(
      response => response,
      error => {
        const { response } = error;
        return this.handleError(response);
      }
    );
  }
```

and when i need to use the credentials in the calls in the frontend i added them like this

```
export const checkUser = async (cookie: string) => {
  const clientAPI = new APIClient();
  clientAPI.client.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  clientAPI.client.defaults.headers.Cookie = cookie;
  const response = await clientAPI.client.get<User>("/users");
  return response.data;
};
```

this was working on my localhost, but since i deployed everything, now is having problems